# dependencies issue when adding library AAR

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've created an Android library that I want to be able to use in other Android applications. I've created a small test app in the same project as the library and everything works.

To test integration with other apps, I created a new application, and followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency) to import my library to that new application by creating a new module from the library's AAR file.

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':my-sdk')
    ...
}
```

settings.gradle file:

```
include ':app', ':my-sdk'
```

Compilation succeeded and I can use the library's API inside the test app, but when running it I get a runtime exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/MediaType;

I assume it's a dependencies issue, since the library uses `okhttp` as a dependency, which is probably not being packed in the AAR file. I just couldn't find anywhere how to compile this dependency so it would work in other projects.

Comment: A JAR or AAR does not have dependency information in it. Publish the AAR to an artifact repository (e.g., a Maven-style repository, using the `maven` plugin for Gradle), and the repository metadata (e.g., POM file) will have the transitive dependency information. Projects that compile against the repository's artifact will pull in those transitive dependencies automatically.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have the same problem and I don't want to publish my library (I want to use it in Unity3d) is there another way to extract dependencies while building my library?

Comment: @FarshidABZ: Not if you are packaging it as a JAR. If you only use the library module in one project, just have that library module in the project itself, as full source, and the transitive dependencies will be honored. Otherwise, *by definition*, you are publishing the library. I have not used Unity3D and cannot comment on how it uses Android libraries.

Comment: "I actually tried that" -- I do not know what that means in the context of your question. For example, you would not use that import process with a library artifact in a repository. You would add your repository to your `repositories` and then have a simple `compile` statement for the library. "I'm pretty sure I'm missing some configuration somewhere" -- if you used a Maven-style repository, check the contents of the POM file in that repository, and see if it has your transitive dependencies listed in there.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unity3d doesn't use maven so we have to copy jar/AAR file into the project. if I understand correctly, I can publish my library and extract AAR file with dependencies and put it into another project.

Is there are any tutorial link to use it?

Comment: @FarshidABZ: I do not know what "extract AAR file with dependencies" means. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, specifically tagged for Unity3D, and ask for advice there.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it adding jar files instead of using maven into my module, then assemble release aar, and in the app project disabling "Instant Run".